# Pymongo inefficient query

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I currently have the following piece of code:

```py
houses = self.database[self.database_name][constants.DATABASE_HOUSES_COLLECTION]           

bulk_houses = houses.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

for house in houses.find().skip(self.from_index).limit(
        constants.MAX_HOUSE_FUNCTION_DOCUMENTS_PER_THREAD):

    house_coords = (house.get("longitude"), house.get("latitude"))

    min = 10000

    for c in self.collection.find({"city": house.get("city")}, {"longtitude": 1, "latitude": 1}):

        collection_coords = (c.get("longitude"), c.get("latitude"))

        distance = geopy.distance.distance(collection_coords, house_coords).km

        if distance < min:
            min = distance

    if min == 10000:
        min = None

    bulk_houses.find({"_id": house.get("_id")}).update(
        {"$set": {f"demography.distanceClosest{translated.get(self.collection.name)}": min}})

bulk_houses.execute()
```

What it does is it goes over each house in the house collection.

For each house it goes over the second collection that has been given and only grabs the longtitude and latitude.

It calculates the closest distance within the same city.

This function is multi threaded, I call the function like this:

```py
houses_count = self.houses.count_documents({})

for i in range(len(self.collections)):

    x = 0
    while x < houses_count:
        match_demography_house = MatchDemographyHouse(self.collections[i], self.mongo_db,
                                                        constants.DATABASE_NAME, x,
                                                        x + constants.MAX_HOUSE_FUNCTION_DOCUMENTS_PER_THREAD)
        match_demography_house.add_to_pool(self.match_house_demography_executor)
        x += constants.MAX_HOUSE_FUNCTION_DOCUMENTS_PER_THREAD
```

And well as you can imagine it's very inefficient. Adding an index on city improved the speed a tiny amount and also only grabbing the longtitude and latitude increased the speed a bit.

It takes 1 minute to go over 1000 houses and the collection that it's going through has 240 documents. It does 50 houses per thread currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this test harness. On my machine it runs in less than a second with no indexing:

```
import pymongo
import random
import datetime
import geopy.distance

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['testhouses']

db.testhouses.delete_many({})
db.testcollection.delete_many({})

for i in range(1000):
    longitude = random.randint(-89, 89)
    latitude = random.randint(-180, 180)
    city = f'City {i}'
    db.testhouses.insert_one({'city': city, 'longitude': longitude, 'latitude': latitude})
    if i < 240:
        db.testcollection.insert_one({'city': city, 'longitude': longitude, 'latitude': latitude})

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

bulk_houses = db.testhouses.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

for house in db.testhouses.find():
    house_coords = (house.get("longitude"), house.get("latitude"))
    minimum = 10000

    for c in db.testcollection.find({"city": house.get("city")}, {"longtitude": 1, "latitude": 1}):
        collection_coords = (c.get("longitude"), c.get("latitude"))
        distance = geopy.distance.distance(collection_coords, house_coords).km

        if distance < minimum: minimum = distance

    if minimum == 10000: minimum = None

    bulk_houses.find({"_id": house.get("_id")}).update({"$set": {f"demography.distanceClosest": minimum}})

result = bulk_houses.execute()
print(f'Bulk updates: {result["nModified"]} updated')
print(f'Time taken: {(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).microseconds / 1000000} seconds')
```

Comment: You're right, it runs in less than a second. I just tested it on my code and I get the same results but with 50 houses. I have tried removing the skip and all the other stuff to match yours but it's still the same. https://gist.github.com/Emre-Saxion/58f3c3d99b28ea607d1eed5eed0aa1ec

Comment: I figured out what was slowing it down, the distance calculation is very slow. But I believe it can still be faster.

Comment: I suspect your whole skip/batch/thread approach is adding way too mcuch overhead. That's why I stripped it all out. The distnace calculation is included in the test harness so not sure why it is slow in your example.